# Tense problem. Retelling a story and asking questions

Tags: grammar, american-english, tenses

I am reading a story and I need to retell it and then to ask some questions about the plot. So I don’t know what tense I should use. The author himself switches from Present Simple/Continuous to Past Simple from time to time. So I am absolutely confused. Here are some extracts for you to make my question more clear:
1. It **was** December 21st, I **am** 15 and I **am living** through a slump. 
2. I **went** to school. Flash forward a few hours I **am** sitting in the Vice Principal’s office.
Thank you!

Comment: Put everything into the present. For example, _John is 15 and living through a slump. On December 21 he goes to school. A few hours later he is sitting in the VP's office because he has hit another student..._ The same applies to the questions: _What does his mother say when he gets home?_

Comment: @Shoe thank you! Is it a mistake if I put everything into the past? As far as I understand the key is to use ONE tense and not mix it with others. Is it right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, English has only two tenses: past and present. So the present simple, present continuous and present perfect are all present tenses. It is common practice to summarize a story or film in the present. (But if you are doing this as a homework assignment, it would be best to ask your teacher.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suit yourself!

You are re-telling it, now it is almost *your* story, especially if you are telling it to children and not a formal audience like in a seminar.

In general, present tense works great, combined with past tense for "flash back" segments of the story.